# Restart later but when?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04

**Ubuntu Software Updater** post update installation shows option below

[image]

I wonder what does *Restart Later* means for Ubuntu.

Windows lets us choose to be reminded in *10 minutes, 1 Hour or 4 Hours*

[image]

So does Macintosh

[image]

After I click on Restart Later at times I see this couple of times in a day and sometimes I see it next day. [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareUpdates#Reminding_you_to_restart) doesn't describe this option very well either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you feel like it. Its worth considering a few things when saying this.

The underlying package manager does *not* force you to reboot - though `/var/run/reboot-required` [will tell you if its needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7042545/674571).

Linux will *hold on to th[e old version of the file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68523/find-and-remove-large-files-that-are-open-but-have-been-deleted) till nothing is using it* , so *typically* a restart is for kernel upgrades, and maybe drivers/modules.

Finally there's a *philosophical* difference between linux (designed for powerusers, and folks who boast about uptime and reliability) and a desktop oriented OS - windows server probably wouldn't force a reboot either.

As such, in linux these reboot warnings are considered *recommended* not *essential* and its informational. There's nothing stopping someone from writing something that ran sudo reboot for you though.

Comment: Found [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1033226) which says **Software Updater should launch automatically ... when ... security updates require a restart to finish installing, and it has been at least 24 hours since you were told about this; or ... non-security updates require a restart to finish installing, and the “When there are other updates” interval has passed since Software Updater was last open (either automatically or manually)** but systems don't seem to go respect it or I'm understanding it totally wrong. Accepting this as it provides more insight

Answer (score 2):

IMHO "Restart later" means simply as it is that **the user** (you) will reboot the system sometime later, that's all!